# C++ GUI Challenge

Tags: c++, graphics, programming-languages, monogame

Recently I was challenged by a friend to create a snake game much like the classic Nokia version using the C++ language.

I have been programming in Java, but unlike Java, C++ doesn't seem to have standard gui libraries.

Therefore after looking into GUI for C++ many different api are available.

Which one would be best for this task?

I use Linux, so something that is cross platform with Windows would be beneficial.

Comment: Recommending apis is off topic for SO

Comment: What about the classic version using ANSI terminal or VT100/52 sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the truly graphical options like Qt, it is also worth considering a simpler one - ncurses. This essentially allows you to create GUI-like interfaces in a terminal and is supported on both Linux and Windows (via Cygwin/MinGW).

This is an example that I made back in university during the summer after a C programming module. It's quite simple graphics wise, but it is a fully functioning snake game.

[image: Snake Game with N-Curses Library]

Answer (score 3):

There are many GUI frameworks for C++, especially [Qt](http://qt.io). You can also use [GTK+](http://gtk.org) for Linux, or [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned there are several API and that comes down to opinion. I would suggest Qt. It is cross platform and I know many people use it.

http://www.qt.io/

Answer (score 1):

I have been using FLTK (http://www.fltk.org/) as it's quite simple to use. Otherwise there are the below cross platform libs:
QT, wxWidget, GTK, CEGYUI (http://cegui.org.uk/), JUCE (http://www.juce.com/) to name a few.